# Scrape the university name (in QS World University Rankings website) with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rank, httr

I want to scrape 2021 University Ranking data from the QS World University Rankings website (https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/world-university-rankings/2021) with R.

I found the latest worked code (ref: (https://www.reddit.com/r/webscraping/comments/ns1l8m/web_scraping_qs_data_with_rvest/))

```
library(httr)

response <- GET("https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/en/2057712.txt?1622792449?v=1622946607402")

data_json <- content(response, encoding = "UTF-8")

data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data_json)

df <- data.frame(data)
```

But I run this code today, I found some error notification

```
Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
```

Can someone please tell me what the function to extract the data ((https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/en/2057712.txt?1622792449?v=1622946607402)) to data frame?

Comment: Hi Teerut! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a look at `data_json` - it doesn't appear to actually be json, despite the name

Comment: ...and when I open the page, it has a Cloudflare captcha. `"Just a moment...\n    \n    \n        \n            \n                \n                    \n                        \n                    \n                    \n                        Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue\n..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark pointed out, the site uses CloudFlare protection, which rules out static scrapers and http clients like `httr` or `rvest`. [User agreement](https://www.topuniversities.com/user-agreement) is also explicit regarding any automated access and scraping. What makes it a bit controversial is the data copyright - https://www.topuniversities.com/data-copyright , `CC BY-NC-ND` (copy - good; derivatives - bad). So retrieval from 3rd parties for personal use seems fine, and the site holder has presumably granted access to some crawlers -- at some point there was a CloudFlare banner about the site being offline and content being served from WayBackMachine snapshot.

And that particular dataset is also mirrored by [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20230201000000*/https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/en/2057712.txt?1622792449?v=1622946607402), last save is from 2023-03-28.
For easy retrieval we could use `archiveRetriever` package:

```r
library(archiveRetriever)
url_ <- "https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/en/2057712.txt?1622792449?v=1622946607402"
ranking_mementos <- retrieve_urls(homepage  = url_,
                                  startDate = "2023-01-01",
                                  endDate   = format(Sys.Date()))
ranking_mementos
#> [1] "http://web.archive.org/web/20230328102439/https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/en/2057712.txt?1622792449?v=1622946607402"
latest <- ranking_mementos[length(ranking_mementos)]
jsonlite::fromJSON(latest)$data |> tibble::as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 1,184 × 13
#>    core_id country city  guide nid   title logo  score rank_display region stars
#>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>        <chr>  <chr>
#>  1 410     United… Camb… ""    2948… "<di… /sit… 100   1            North… ""   
#>  2 573     United… Stan… ""    2972… "<di… /sit… 98.4  2            North… ""   
#>  3 253     United… Camb… ""    2942… "<di… /sit… 97.9  3            North… ""   
#>  4 94      United… Pasa… ""    2945… "<di… /sit… 97    4            North… ""   
#>  5 478     United… Oxfo… ""    2946… "<di… /sit… 96.7  5            Europe ""   
#>  6 201     Switze… Züri… ""    2944… "<di… /sit… 95    6            Europe ""   
#>  7 95      United… Camb… ""    2945… "<di… /sit… 94.3  7            Europe ""   
#>  8 356     United… Lond… ""    2940… "<di… /sit… 93.6  8            Europe ""   
#>  9 120     United… Chic… ""    2945… "<di… /sit… 93.1  9            North… ""   
#> 10 365     United… Lond… ""    2940… "<di… /sit… 92.9  10           Europe ""   
#> # ℹ 1,174 more rows
#> # ℹ 2 more variables: recm <chr>, dagger <lgl>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

At the time of writing, the current online version is identical to this archived one. However, note that it does not seem to be in use anymore when serving regular user-initiated web requests.